# typescript Redis client in constructor of class?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, node-redis

I have a typescript class which I want to use redis in, my thoughts were to set up and connect to redis in another module and pass that into the constructor, so that I can also mock the redis client in unit tests. It'd be something like this:

redis.ts

```js
import { createClient } from "redis";
import config from "../../config";

const redisClient = createClient({ url: config.redis_url });
redisClient.connect();

export default redisClient;
```

MyService.ts

```js
export default class MyService {
  private cacheClient: RedisClientType;
  
  constructor(redisClient: RedisClientType) {
    this.cacheClient = redisClient;
  }
}
```

Then to use it like:

```js
import redisClient from "./redis"
import MyService from "./MyService"

const myService = new MyService(redisClient);
```

but I'm getting an error when I try this.  Argument of type 'redisClientType {...lots of extra stuff...} is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisClientType'

I'm looking for a good example of using redis with strongly typed typescript and mocking that will allow me to unit test more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem for [Redis OM](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node/). You're welcome to spelunk the code and see what there is too see.

The key thing for me was in defining the type of the Redis connection returned by Node Redis when I called `.createClient` or `.createCluster`. Here's how I did it:

```js
/** A conventional Redis connection. */
export type RedisClientConnection = ReturnType<typeof createClient>

/** A clustered Redis connection. */
export type RedisClusterConnection = ReturnType<typeof createCluster>

/** A Redis connection, clustered or conventional. */
export type RedisConnection = RedisClientConnection | RedisClusterConnection
```

Hope this helps!